# IOS Xamarin - Realtime plot draw lines

Tags: ios, plot, xamarin.ios, xamarin, draw

I'm working in a cross test project for display ecg graph in realtime. it's work fine on windows and android using Xamarin, BUT in IOS i have slow and slow performarces.

I think the problem is due to my lack of expertise in ios..

I've done two tests both failed, someone have a solutions to speed up ?

TEST A

I call Plot and then assign the UIImage wBitmap as MyView Backgroud every < 10ms

```
    public void Plot(PointF pPrec, PointF pNext)
    {
    SizeF bitmapSize = new SizeF(wBitmap.Size);
    using (CGBitmapContext context2 = new CGBitmapContext(IntPtr.Zero, (int)bitmapSize.Width, (int)bitmapSize.Height, 8, (int)(4 * bitmapSize.Width), CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
    {
        context2.DrawImage(new RectangleF(0, 0, wBitmap.Size.Width, wBitmap.Size.Height), wBitmap.CGImage);
        context2.SetLineWidth(1);
        context2.AddLineToPoint(pNext.X, pNext.Y);
        context2.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);
        // output the drawing to the view
        wBitmap = UIImage.FromImage(context2.ToImage());
    }
}
```

TEST B

I call Plot and then assign the UIImage wBitmap as MyView Backgroud every < 10ms

```
    public void Plot2(PointF pPrec, PointF pNext) { UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(wBitmap.Size); context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    using (context)
    {
        if (wBitmap != null)
        {
            context.TranslateCTM(0f, wBitmap.Size.Height);
            context.ScaleCTM(1.0f, -1.0f);
            context.DrawImage(new RectangleF(0f, 0f, wBitmap.Size.Width, wBitmap.Size.Height), wBitmap.CGImage);
            context.ScaleCTM(1.0f, -1.0f);
            context.TranslateCTM(0f, -wBitmap.Size.Height);
        } 

        context.SetLineWidth(1);
        context.MoveTo(pPrec.X, pPrec.Y);
        context.AddLineToPoint(pNext.X, pNext.Y);
        context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);

wBitmap = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


    }//end using cont
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to call this every 10ms?  Seems like overkill.

Comment: Yes ECG program in realtime send every 2ms a sample (x,y coords) i can discard 5 sample for decimation, the draw process make a new point every 10ms. On Galaxy tab 3 Android and Windows Samsung ATIV is work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to draw into a bitmap first and then use that bitmap in a view. The correct approach to this is to subclass `UIView` and then override the `Draw()` method and paint your stuff in there.

You can then call `SetNeedsDisplay()` on the view to schedule a redraw.

The example below draw an arrow shaped background:

```
class YourView: UIView
{
public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
{
    const float inset = 15f;
    UIColor.Blue.SetFill();
    var path = new UIBezierPath();
    path.MoveTo(new PointF(0, 0));
    path.AddLineTo(new PointF(rect.Width - inset, 0));
    path.AddLineTo(new PointF(rect.Width, rect.Height * 0.5f));
    path.AddLineTo(new PointF(rect.Width - inset, rect.Bottom));
    path.AddLineTo(new PointF(0, rect.Bottom));
    path.AddLineTo(new PointF(0, 0));
    path.Fill();
}
}
}
```

Alternatively you might want to look at existing components, like [CorePlot](http://components.xamarin.com/view/coreplot) or [TeeChart](https://components.xamarin.com/view/TeeChart) available in the Xamarin Components store. TeeChart would even be cross platform, so you wouldn't have to worry about Android vs. iOS.